# Getting e-mails from sites I have not registered to

Tags: email, gmail, phishing

I have been getting e-mails from sites like instagram for accounts I did not create. The weird thing is, the e-mails are sent to the address `namelastname@gmail.com` when my e-mail address is `name.lastname@gmail.com`.

Is this something to worry about? Why am I getting e-mails that seem to have been sent to a different e-mail address?

Comment: Are you able to provide an example email? They could be spoofing the `to` address so if you can show the email headers as well that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why am I getting e-mails that seem to have been sent to a different e-mail address?

`namelastname@gmail.com`  and `name.lastname@gmail.com` are **both** your email address. See below for more information.

Possiblities:

1. Someone has signed up to Instagram using your email address:

   If that is the case you should be able to take over the instagram account (using https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/ to reset the password) and delete it if you want.
2. namelastname@gmail.com is on some spammers list and you are receiving spam, and it is nothing to do with Instagram at all:

   Flag it as spam in Gmail. Eventually you won't see such emails in your Inbox.

---

#### Gmail does not recognize dots in an email address

> Gmail does not recognize dots in an email address, so  firstname...@gmail.com and  firstnam...@gmail.com are both yours.  (FYI, you can sign into your account using either address).  Someone has mistakenly been using  firstnam...@gmail.com as their email address so these emails have been coming to you (think of it as someone giving out a wrong phone number which happens to be yours).  Your email is not going to another person since you 'own' both accounts.  See this link (http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10313) for more info.

Source [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/kC-rqArdWvU)

---

#### Receiving someone else's mail

> Your address is similar but has more or fewer dots (.) or different
> capitalization.
>
> Sometimes you may receive a message sent to an address that looks like
> yours but has a different number or arrangement of periods. While we
> know it might be unnerving if you think someone else's mail is being
> routed to your account, don't worry: both of these addresses are
> yours.
>
> Gmail doesn't recognize dots as characters within usernames, you can
> add or remove the dots from a Gmail address without changing the
> actual destination address; they'll all go to your inbox, and only
> yours. In short:
>
> - homerjsimpson@gmail.com = hom.er.j.sim.ps.on@gmail.com
> - homerjsimpson@gmail.com = HOMERJSIMPSON@gmail.com
> - homerjsimpson@gmail.com = Homer.J.Simpson@gmail.com
>
> All these addresses belong to the same person. You can see this if you
> try to sign in with your username, but adding or removing a dot from
> it. You'll still go to your account.
>
> If you get mail that seems to be intended for someone else, it's
> likely that the sender entered the wrong address, just like if you've
> ever dialed a wrong phone number for someone. In these cases, we
> suggest contacting the original sender or website when possible to
> alert them to the mistake.
>
> One last thing: Google Apps does recognize dots. If you'd like to have
> a dot in your username, please ask your domain administrator to add
> your preferred username as a nickname.

Source [Receiving someone else's mail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en)

Comment: I was surprised initially when I learned about the "dot blindness" but it makes perfect sense. If someone else could register the same address with only a period difference, that would be... bad. Also, penalizing someone for leaving out the dot would be... unhelpful.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about the dot blindness. I already have an instagram account. I guess I'll mark all the other weird stuff as spam.

Comment: Wow, what a great answer. I had no idea Gmail did this, do you know if other email providers do a similar thing (Yahoo, Hotmail, et al)?

Comment: @Burgi Yahoo doesn't. I've got both formats and they are separate accounts. Don't know about the others.